# Why the custom at the end of Tashlich to shake off Tzitzis?

Tags: minhag, tzitzis, rosh-hashanah-new-year, repentance-teshuvah, tashlich

In the Siddur Nussach Ari it says by the end of Tashlich to shake the ends of your Tzitzis, I heard that this symbolizes the tossing of a persons sins in the depth of the water (as in the verse " ותשליך במצולות ים כל חטאתם"  (Micah [7:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16193#v=18)-20) "You will cast all their sins into the depths of the sea."

Does anyone have a source for this?
Also, if it is true, then why the need for further Teshuva (in the rest of the ten days of Repentance)?

In the Sefer Taamei Haminhagim: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=332 it says that the reason we do it is to shake off the Kelipos which are attached to us when we do a sin, so the question is does that mean we are ridding ourselves of the actual sins?

Comment: If a murderer and rapist shakes some strings near some water he is forgiven for all his sins???

Comment: @doubleaa. And 10 days of repentance does help??

Comment: @men If they repent sincerely, then they can always be forgiven. It sounds easier than it is, though.

Comment: EHS You've edited what seems like an answer to your question. You should post it as such and ask new questions as [new questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @DoubleAA i was just trying to point out that in my understanding "Klipos" don't seem like sins